# In some systems, is it impossible for the stack and the heap of a process to collide?

Tags: c, memory, stack, heap-memory

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334055/what-happens-when-stack-and-heap-collide) about what happens when a process' stack and heap collide with each other.

However, I was doing some tests on my Linux, to check if I could force a collision! So here's what I did:

1. Wrote the below C program to check the "bounds" of the process' address space using `gdb`. I found the "limits" by performing a binary search using the `gdb`'s `x` command until it finds an address it can't access anymore.

```c
int main(void) {
    int x;
}
```

2. I found that:

   - The beginning of the code section (and therefore of the whole address space) of the process memory is at address `0x555555554000`
   - The (initial) inferior limit of the heap is at `0x555555579fff`
   - The superior limit/"top" of the stack is at `0x7fffff7ff000`
   - The inferior limit of the stack is at `0x7fffffffefff`
3. This is generally consistent across different processes
4. So, the amount of memory to force a collision is the difference between the inferior limit of the heap and the superior limit of the stack: `0x7fffff7ff000 - 0x555555579fff = 46912487575545` bytes, equivalent to 43690 GiB (!!)
5. It is clearly impossible to force this collision.

Am I correct or wrong? If correct, is there any system that I could use to force a collision? If wrong, what did I get wrong?

Worth noting that I searched the web for a while, asking if this was really impossible, but I didn't find any resource talking about this. They all assume that it is possible for the collision to occur.

Comment: *"5. It is clearly impossible to force this collision."* why do you think this?

Comment: @JohnFilleau because of the last phrase in the 4th point: The difference is 43690 GiB, which is a request impossible for the OS to fulfill

Comment: On 64-bit systems, such a collision is improbable.  On 32-bit systems, it was possible if you got too greedy.

Comment: 44 terabytes is pretty big, but not impossibly big.  Note well that you don't have to have physical RAM to back allocations -- they can be backed by virtual memory just as well, and in some cases, virtual memory may be backed by *nothing*. But I routinely work with workstations that have tens of terabytes of local storage, so it's possible for 44 terabytes of virtual memory to be backed by actual storage, too.  But maybe not on your particular computer.

Comment: Additionally, it's not necessarily the case that you have to allocate anywhere near the full amount of space you describe.  By strategic (or unfortunate) choice of address for shared libraries and / or memory mappings, it is possible to force a subsequent, fulfillable heap allocation to pretty much as high an address as is available.  You can then force the stack to grow down into a collision by, say, a not too outrageously deep recursion.

Comment: How "write to stack" differs from "write to heap" from CPU's point of view?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yup, I was thinking only about my particular machine, which has 8GB RAM. I got curious about "*Note well that you don't have to have physical RAM to back allocations*". If I `malloc`'d something greater than my available physical RAM (as is the case here), wouldn't the call fail and return 0? I just tried that. "*Force a subsequent, fulfillable heap allocation to pretty much as high an address as is available*" I didn't understand that. Could you care to explain? Or, if not, point me to somewhere useful for understanding this forcing?

Comment: The amount of RAM is irrelevant. User-mode processes use virtual memory.

Comment: Some systems like RTOS microcontrollers do not even support heap allocation, so yes it is impossible to have the stack collide with something that isn't there.